Frontend not connecting to backend in aks, using Ingress
I have my services deployed on aks, where one of the services frontend is exposed using load-balancer and frontend is suppose to request data from 2 different micro services, but I am not able to receive data on the website.
Also I tried to request directly to the ingress,considering i was doing something wrong in the frontend still i got 404 error.
my ingress resource file looks something like this:




apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: bert-ingress  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /reinforcement
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: bertreinforcement
            port:
              number: 5000
      - path: /environment
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: bertenvironment
            port:
              number: 8080






all my ports and names are fine.
Here is the request i tried sending: 
(base) b:~$ curl -I http://<IngressIP>/reinforcement/get_prediction_result
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2024 05:44:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 146
Connection: keep-alive

(base) b:~$ curl -I http://<IngressIP>/environment/get_result
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2024 05:44:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 146
Connection: keep-alive

similar response for other micro service also, my code has the endpoint correctly set,
what can be the reason? I am doing this for the first time, is this related to ingress resource file? or is it something related to wrong procedure of exposing my internal ,micro services?

Hi , does your backend services expect a specific path ? –

The issue, I can see is this bit- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target annotation rewrites the URL path before forwarding it to the backend service, which can lead to 404 errors if not configured correctly.
Hence I am going to assume - which is you don't intend to rewrite paths in this case simply removing this bit below should solve the problem.
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /   <- remove from your yaml


The issue is resolved. It was a small issue with the specific path mentioned in the backend. I just put the endpoint there and it worked, thanks.
this worked:
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: bert-ingress  namespace: default
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    spec:
      ingressClassName: nginx
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - path: /get_prediction_result
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: bertreinforcement
                port:
                  number: 5000
          - path: /get_result
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: bertenvironment
                port:
                  number: 8080

